# Scala: Run a function that is written for arrays on a dataframe that contains column of array

Tags: scala, apache-spark

So, I have the following functions that work perfectly when I use them on arrays:

```
def magnitude(x: Array[Int]): Double = {
    math.sqrt(x map(i => i*i) sum)
}

def dotProduct(x: Array[Int], y: Array[Int]): Int = {
    (for((a, b) <- x zip y) yield a * b) sum
}

def cosineSimilarity(x: Array[Int], y: Array[Int]): Double = {
    require(x.size == y.size)
    dotProduct(x, y)/(magnitude(x) * magnitude(y))
}
```

But, I don't know how to run it on an array that I have in a spark dataframe column.
[image]

I know the problem is that the function expects an array, but I am giving a column to it. But, I don't know how to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to wrap your functions within UDFs. Yet UDFs are known to be suboptimal most of the time. You could therefore rewrite your functions with spark primitives. To ease the reuse of the expression you write, you can write functions that take `Column` objects as parameters.

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.Column

def magnitude(x : Column) = {
    aggregate(transform(x, _ * _), lit(0), _ + _)
}

def dotProduct(x : Column, y : Column) = {
    val products = transform(arrays_zip(x, y), s => s(x.toString) * s(y.toString))
    aggregate(products, lit(0), _ + _)
}

def cosineSimilarity(x : Column, y : Column) = {
    dotProduct(x, y) / (magnitude(x) * magnitude(y))
}
```

Let's test this:

```scala
val df = spark.range(1).select(
    array(lit(1), lit(2), lit(3)) as "x",
    array(lit(1), lit(3), lit(5)) as "y"
)

df.select(
    'x, 'y,
    magnitude('x) as "magnitude_x",
    dotProduct('x, 'y) as "dot_prod_x_y",
    cosineSimilarity('x, 'y) as "cosine_x_y"
).show()
```

which yields:

```
+---------+---------+-----------+------------+--------------------+
|        x|        y|magnitude_x|dot_prod_x_y|          cosine_x_y|
+---------+---------+-----------+------------+--------------------+
|[1, 2, 3]|[1, 3, 5]|         14|          22|0.044897959183673466|
+---------+---------+-----------+------------+--------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

To use your own functions within sparkSQL, you need to wrap them inside of a UDF (user defined function).

```scala
val df = spark.range(1)
    .withColumn("x", array(lit(1), lit(2), lit(3)))

// defining the user defined functions from the scala functions.
val magnitude_udf = udf(magnitude _)
val dot_product_udf = udf(dotProduct(_,_))

df
    .withColumn("magnitude", magnitude_udf('x))
    .withColumn("dot_product", dot_product_udf('x, 'x))
    .show
```

```
+---+---------+------------------+-----------+
| id|        x|         magnitude|dot_product|
+---+---------+------------------+-----------+
|  0|[1, 2, 3]|3.7416573867739413|         14|
+---+---------+------------------+-----------+
```

Comment: Thanks, Oli. the other question would be I know that using UDF gets in the way of spark optimization. Is there any other way to not use UDF and still get the output that we want?

Comment: I added another answer using spark primitives.